# Yii renderPartial working on localserver (xampp) but not on normal host

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii's user module and I have in the profile view a renderPartial view of another controller's action

```
<div class="row">
<?php $model2 = new Symptomhistory; ?>
<?php $this->renderPartial('//symptomhistory\_usersHistory',array('model'=>$model2)); ?>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly when I run it on my local server, but when I upload it to my host I get the following error:

```
CException

ProfileController cannot find the requested view "//symptomhistory\usersHistory".
```

I tried going to the path with "....\ect.. ect..\views\symptomhistory\usersHistory" too but it doesn't work. Is it a problem with my server? Because if it is it's a weird one since all the other renderPartials work fine, it's just this one that it can't find.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely running xampp on windows right? Don't ever use backslashes as path separators, always use forward slashes.

So your command should be:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('//symptomhistory/_usersHistory', array('model' => $model2)); ?>
```